# How do I include vendor scripts in the JSPM CLI when creating an SFX bundle?

Tags: jspm

`System.import` slows down considerably when importing vendor scripts, so I'm including them as `script` tags in my HTML file and removing the code by using `htmlprocessor`.

```
<!-- build:js assets/index.js -->
<script src="system.js"></script>
<script src="jspm_packages/npm/vue-router%400.7.13/dist/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="jspm_packages/npm/vue%401.0.26/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('./index');
</script>
<!-- /build -->
```

However, now when I use the JSPM CLI, I won't have any vendor scripts. How can I include these vendor scripts when I run `jspm bundle-sfx` using the JSPM CLI?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against taking that route. The `jspm bundle-sfx` command creates a self-contained-production-ready bundle, which means all the necessary vendor dependencies would be included. Something like this would suffice (where `bundle.js` is the output file of `jspm bundle-sfx` — i.e. `jspm bundle-sfx app/main.js bundle.js`):

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import(app);
</script>
```

If you are missing files in `bundle.js`, it's likely a bug of some sort and an issue report might need to be filed with JSPM CLI. Also, I'm assuming you are using jspm 0.16, the jspm 0.17-beta now uses the `jspm build` instead of `jspm bundle-sfx`. I hope that helps!